# replace multiple tabspace with space in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a text file. I am reading all data from that text file. I have given code like this for removing all tab spaces with space.but this code is not working

```
 sr = New StreamReader(Filename)
        temp_data = sr.ReadLine
        While Not temp_data = Nothing
            sTemp = Split(temp_data, "|", -1)
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To sTemp.Length - 1
                sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), ",", "")
                sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), "'", "")
                sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), """", "")
                sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), vbTab, "")

            Next
```

in my text file i have some string like this:

```
treading of pin                                                            of roller small large
```

Comment: dear all some time i am getting two or three tab space so how i can replace that?

Comment: Hard to guess what "tab spaces" are when looking at the code.  Just provide a practical example of "not working", no need to force us to guess.

Comment: i editted my question as per your requeriment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace tabs with spaces you shall put a space between double quotes.

Comment: yes, I'm under the impression you'd like to replace what's on the left with what's on the right. If you want to replace a tab with a space, you shall put a space between quotes

Comment: sir so i can go with what i suggest?

Comment: some time i am getting two or three tab space so how i can replace that

Comment: Makes no difference. You are processing one character at a time, so all tabs will be processed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion those aren't tabs, but multiple spaces.
You should

```
                sTemp(i) = Replace(sTemp(i), "  ", " ")
```

replace two spaces with one, and see whether this makes any difference.